# Aysnc module callback function is called before first function is finish execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am using async module version 0.9.0 and sequelize module  1.7.9 in my project . Using the auto function of Async module to call sequelize function one by one . I need to call second function when first function is completed and return the value it is suppose to return.

```
exports.createUser = function (req, authenticatedUser, res) {

    configurationHolder.sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
        async.auto({
            checkAuthority:checkAuthorityToCreateUserWrapper(authenticatedUser, req.body.authority, res,t),
            checkEmail: ['checkAuthority',checkEmailWrapper(req.body.email, req.body.username, res,t)],
            address: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority',createAddressWrapper(t, req.body.lineOne, req.body.lineTwo, req.body.pin, req.body.cityId, req.body.countryId, req.body.regionId, res)],
            role: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority','address', findRoleWrapper(t, req, req.body.authority, authenticatedUser, res)],
            user: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority','address','role',createUserWrapper(t, req.body.password, req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, req.body.gender, req.body.email, res)],
            userWithRole: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority','address','role', addRoleToUserWrapper(t, req.body.authority, res)],
            userWithAddress: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority','address','role', 'userWithRole', addAddressToUserWrapper(t, req, res)],
            authorizationToken: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority','address','role', 'userWithRole','userWithAddress', createAuthorizationTokenWrapper(t, req, res)],
            userWithAuthorizationToken: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority','address','role', 'userWithRole','userWithAddress', 'authorizationToken', addAuthorizationTokenToUserWrapper(t, req, res)]
        }, function (err, results) {
            console.log("err === " + err)
            if (err) {
                console.log("err ================================ " + err)
                 var error = err
                 t.rollback().success(function (err) {
                    configurationHolder.responseUtil.responseHandler(res, results, error, true, 200)
                })
             } else {
                t.commit().success(function (err) {
                    configurationHolder.responseUtil.responseHandler(res, results, null, true, 200)
                })
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Code is executing every function mention in the Async in defined order but in results it is returning value of first 4 function only i.e checkAuthority,checkEmail,address,role.

I have debug using printing the timestamp and it seems to me before completing the first function next function is called .

full code is given below :

```
exports.createUser = function (req, authenticatedUser, res) {

    configurationHolder.sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
        async.auto({
            checkAuthority:checkAuthorityToCreateUserWrapper(authenticatedUser, req.body.authority, res,t),
            checkEmail: ['checkAuthority',checkEmailWrapper(req.body.email, req.body.username, res,t)],
            address: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority',createAddressWrapper(t, req.body.lineOne, req.body.lineTwo, req.body.pin, req.body.cityId, req.body.countryId, req.body.regionId, res)],
            role: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority','address', findRoleWrapper(t, req, req.body.authority, authenticatedUser, res)],
            user: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority','address','role',createUserWrapper(t, req.body.password, req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, req.body.gender, req.body.email, res)],
            userWithRole: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority','address','role', addRoleToUserWrapper(t, req.body.authority, res)],
            userWithAddress: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority','address','role', 'userWithRole', addAddressToUserWrapper(t, req, res)],
            authorizationToken: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority','address','role', 'userWithRole','userWithAddress', createAuthorizationTokenWrapper(t, req, res)],
            userWithAuthorizationToken: ['checkEmail','checkAuthority','address','role', 'userWithRole','userWithAddress', 'authorizationToken', addAuthorizationTokenToUserWrapper(t, req, res)]
        }, function (err, results) {
            console.log("err === " + err)
            if (err) {
                console.log("err ================================ " + err)
                 var error = err
                 t.rollback().success(function (err) {
                    configurationHolder.responseUtil.responseHandler(res, results, error, true, 200)
                })
             } else {
                t.commit().success(function (err) {
                    configurationHolder.responseUtil.responseHandler(res, results, null, true, 200)
                })
            }
        })
    });
}


//wrapper function starts here 

function checkAuthorityToCreateUserWrapper(authenticatedUser, authority, res,t){
    return function(next){
        checkAuthorityToCreateUser(authenticatedUser, authority, res,next,t)
    }
}

function createAddressWrapper(t, lineOne, lineTwo, pin, cityId, countryId, regionId, res,t) {
    console.log("ADDRESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS")
    return function (next, results) {
        createAddress(t, lineOne, lineTwo, pin, cityId, countryId, regionId, next, results, res,t)
    }
}

function addRoleToUserWrapper(t, authority, res) {

    return function (next, results) {
        addRoleToUser(t,next, results,authority, res)
    }
}

function addAddressToUserWrapper(t, req, res) {
    return function (next, results) {
        addAddressToUser(t, req, res, next, results)
    }
}

function findRoleWrapper(t, req, authority, authenticatedUser, res) {
    return function (next, results) {
        findRole(t, next, results, authority, authenticatedUser, res)
    }
}

function createUserWrapper(t, password, firstName, lastName, gender, email, res) {
    return function (next, results) {
        createUserExecution(t,next, results, password, firstName, lastName, gender, email)
    }
}

function checkEmailWrapper(email, username, res,t) {
    return function (next,results) {
        checkEmail(next,results, email, username, res,t)
    }
}

function createAuthorizationTokenWrapper(t, req, res) {
    return function (next, results) {
        createAuthorizationToken(next, results, t, req, res)
    }
}

function addAuthorizationTokenToUserWrapper(t, req, res) {
    return function (next, results) {
        addAuthorizationTokenToUser(next, results, t, req, res)
    }
}
//wrapper function ends here

function checkEmail(next,results, email, username, res,t) {
    domain.AuthorizationToken.find({
        where: configurationHolder.sequelize.or({
            "email": email
        }, {
            "username": username
        })
    },{transaction:t}).complete(function (err, emailCheckUser) {
        if (err != null) {
            next(err,null)
           // configurationHolder.responseUtil.responseHandler(res, null, configurationHolder.errorMessage.unique, true, 400)
        } else if (emailCheckUser != null) {
            next(configurationHolder.errorMessage.unique, null)
            //configurationHolder.responseUtil.responseHandler(res, null, configurationHolder.errorMessage.unique, true, 400)
        } else{
            domain.User.find({where:{"email":email}}).complete(function(err,userCheck){
                if(err != null || userCheck != null){
                    next(configurationHolder.errorMessage.unique, null)
                }else{
                    next(err,{"checkemail":"available"})
                }
            })

        }
    })
}

function checkAuthorityToCreateUser(authenticatedUser, authority, res,next,t) {
    var err = configurationHolder.errorMessage.failedLogin
    console.log("authenticatedUser.role.authority = " + authenticatedUser.role.authority + "   " + authority)
    switch (authenticatedUser.role.authority) {
    case "SUPERADMIN":
        if (authority == "SUPERADMIN_CUSTOMER_SERVICES" || authority == "ADMIN" || authority == "DELEGATE_ADMIN" || authority == "USER") {
            next(null,{allowed:true})
        } else {
            next(configurationHolder.errorMessage.notPermit,{allowed:true})
          //  configurationHolder.responseUtil.responseHandler(res, null, , true, 400)
        }
    case "SUPERADMIN_CUSTOMER_SERVICES":
        if (authority == "ADMIN" || authority == "DELEGATE_ADMIN" || authority == "USER") {
            next(null,{allowed:true})
        } else {
             next(configurationHolder.errorMessage.notPermit,{allowed:true})
        }
    case "ADMIN":
        if (authority == "DELEGATE_ADMIN" || authority == "USER") {
            next(null,{allowed:true})
        } else {
            next(configurationHolder.errorMessage.notPermit,{allowed:true})
        }
    case "DELEGATE_ADMIN":
        if (authority == "USER") {
            next(null,{allowed:true})
        } else {
             next(configurationHolder.errorMessage.notPermit,{allowed:true})
        }
    case "USER":
        if (authority == "USER") {
            next(null,{allowed:true})
        } else {
            next(configurationHolder.errorMessage.notPermit,{allowed:true})
        }
    default:
        if (authority == "USER") {
            next(null,{allowed:true})
        } else {
             next(configurationHolder.errorMessage.notPermit,{allowed:true})
        }
    }

}

function createAddress(t, lineOne, lineTwo, pin, cityId, countryId, regionId, next, results, res) {
    domain.Address.create({
        line_one: lineOne,
        line_two: lineTwo,
        pincode: pin,
        cityId: cityId,
        countryId: countryId,
        regionId: regionId
    }, {
        transaction: t
    }).complete(function (err, address) {
        if (err != null) {
            next(err,null)
          //  t.rollback()
          //  configurationHolder.responseUtil.responseHandler(res, null, err, true, 400)
        } else {
            console.log("address = " + address)
            next(null, address)
        }
    })

}

function findRole(t, next, results, authority, authenticatedUser, res) {
    domain.Role.find({
        where: {
            authority: authority
        }
    }, {
        transaction: t
    }).complete(function (err, role) {
        console.log("role == "+err)
        next(err,role)
    })
}

function createUserExecution(t,next, results, password, firstName, lastName, gender, email) {
    password = crypto.createHmac('sha1', "Admin").update(password).digest('hex')
    domain.User.create({
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        gender: gender,
        email: email,
        salt: email,
        delflag: false
    }, {
        transaction: t
    }).complete(function (err, user) {
        console.log(err);
        next(err, user)
    })

}

function addRoleToUser(t,next, results,authority, res) {
    results.role.setUsers([results.user], {
        transaction: t
    }).complete(next)
}

function addAddressToUser(t, req, res, next, results) {
    results.address.setUsers([results.user], {
        transaction: t
    }).complete(function (err, obj) {
        console.log(err)
        next(err, obj)
    })
}

function createAuthorizationToken(next, results, t, req, res) {
    password = crypto.createHmac('sha1', "Admin").update(req.body.password.toString()).digest('hex')
    domain.AuthorizationToken.create({
        authToken: null,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: password,
        username: req.body.username
    }, {
        transaction: t
    }).complete(function (err, obj) {
        console.log(err)
        next(err, obj)
    })

}

function addAuthorizationTokenToUser(next, results, t, req, res) {
    results.user.setAuthorizationToken(results.authorizationToken, {
        transaction: t
    }).complete(function (err, obj) {
        console.log(err)
        next(err, obj)
    })
}
```

Result I am getting in response is :

```
{
    "error": true,
    "message": null,
    "response": {
        "checkAuthority": {
            "allowed": true
        },
        "checkEmail": {
            "checkemail": "available"
        },
        "address": {
            "line_one": "!soulispure#9911",
            "line_two": "abhimanyu.mailme@gmail.com",
            "pincode": 110062,
            "cityId": 98,
            "countryId": 97,
            "regionId": 99,
            "id": 84
        },
        "role": {
            "id": 5,
            "authority": "USER",
            "createdAt": "2014-11-26T12:24:08.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2014-11-26T12:24:08.000Z",
            "deletedAt": null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On removing **checkAuthority:checkAuthorityToCreateUserWrapper(authenticatedUser, req.body.authority, res,t)** from async it is running fine . but still I am not sure about reason behind this behaviour of my code

Comment: From my experience you cannot control flow of callbacks when using async. You need to do it explicitly by using some of npm module or sequencing to execute your functions only when previous gets completed. Removing the function or response object just lets your process to be in kind of flow but not the actual sequence flow.

Comment: Aysn module is use for control flow . which is working fine when I remove the checkAuthorityToCreateUserWrapper(authenticatedUser, req.body.authority, res,t) function